# how to display 'my wishlist' in header top links in magento

Tags: magento

i upgraded my magento site from 1.4.1.1 to magento 1.7.0.2 .

After that the my wishlist link is not displaying in the header top right .

How can i display this?

I used this code in customer.xml file:

```
<reference name="top.links">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Wishlist</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Wishlist</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</position></action>
</reference>
```

but it does not link to wish list after logging .

So how can i link it itno correct link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add links to header via layout rules like follows. I took this sample for you from  `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml`

```
<reference name="top.links">
    <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="customer"><label>My Account</label><url helper="customer/getAccountUrl"/><title>My Account</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>10</p$
</reference>
```

Comment: @ Anton S,i need to display my wishlist link the other links are displayed.this is the missing one.where should i write the above code ?is it in app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml or else?

Comment: based on that question you asked in comments I think you need to understand Magento layout engine and how it is built with xml and how themes are rendered based on that. Start from magento knowledge base or buy Alan Storm's great "no-frills magento layouts" book for future reference. It is hard to explain it here without doing all the work for you. In general you need to place it to your layout file that gets included in places you need and get the link from your own block or some core blocks already existing